# Insert schema data inside html tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I am wondering if there is a way to insert text, schema data in particular, into a html div tag using javascript.  I know there are methods for modifying existing values inside a tag such as class, href, title, but can't seem to find a way to add something new.

Basically I have `<div id="main">` and I want to modify it to be `<div id="main" itemtype="http://schema.org/SomeCategory" itemscope>` and to be able to remove it later.

The context for such a need is using fetch / js to replace parts of webpages rather than reloading the entire page.  The product pages use the schema notation, whereas general info pages do not, though all templates use the "main" div.

Answer (score 1):

Unbeknownst to me, the `innerHTML` function attached to the body tag allows me to change actual div tags using `replace`. So it is simple:

```
  input ='<div id="main">';
  output='<div id="main" itemtype="http://schema.org/SomeCategory" itemscope>';
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(input,output);
```